# Bootstrap navbar sizing and spacing

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, navbar

I have just begun using bootstrap for building websites and I am unable to get the navbar the way I would like. Ideally I am going for something like this: http://getbootstrap.com/examples/navbar/ where the navbar has padding on the right, left and top but is still centered. I'm assuming this is somewhere in the css style sheet but I haven't been able to find it. Any help you can give on how I can achieve this type of navbar would be appreciated. Below is my code as it stands for the navbar

```
`<!-- Static navbar -->
  <div class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand">Text</a>
    </div>
    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#">text</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">text</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">text</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">text <b class="caret"></b></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">text</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">text</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">text Sync</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">text</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">text</a></li>
      </ul>
      
    </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
  </div>
```

`

Answer (score 2):

Wrap your navbar within a div container like this -

```
 <div class= "container">
     <div class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
    </div>
</div>
```

and also give your .navbar css a padding-bottom 20px like this

```
 .navbar {
     padding-bottom: 20px;
 }
```

Hope this helps

Comment: thanks for the help! I think its almost there, when I add those snippets in it does create a container but when I increase the padding on the top in bottom it looks as though its a container within a container. Any idea on how to deal with that?